# Preencher a tabela com dados do banco. (Mysql e Bootstrap 4.1)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, tabela-html

Salve galera, estou tentando preencher uma tabela com dados vindo diretamente do banco (Mysql). Sou novo em web, consegui montar um esboço do que estou tentando fazer. Se alguém puder dar algumas dicas, ficaria extremamente grato.

```html
<?php 
include "conexao.php" ;
$sql = "Select * from usuario";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$sql); ?>

 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">email</th>
      <th scope="col">senha</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>

<?php 
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
  $email = $dados['email'];
  $senha = $dados['senha']; ?>
 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><?php $email ?></td>
      <td><?php $senha ?></td>
     
    </tr> 
      </tbody>
</table>
  
   <?php } ?>

  </div>
```

Esse o trecho relativo à tabela e o banco.

Comment: Boa tarde, qual o erro?

Comment: a princípio nessas linhas estão falando o `echo`.
`<td><?php echo $email ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $senha ?></td>`

Comment: A princípio eu achei que deixando  essa parte <tr> </tr> dentro do WHILE, as linhas seriam preenchidas, mas não preenchem. No melhor caso que tive, somente a primeira linha foi criada e preenchida.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem do retorno que o código gera.

Comment: Meu amigo, os dados estão abaixo, o problema está no fechamento de suas tags `html`..o `tbody` deve estar fora do `while` e o fechamento das tags também, dentro do `while` deve estar apenas as `<tr>` e `<td>`

Comment: Adicionei como resposta, apenas para te ajudar

Answer (score 2):

Meu amigo, os dados estão abaixo, o problema está no fechamento de suas tags `html`..o `tbody` deve estar fora do `while` e o fechamento das tags também, dentro do `while` deve estar apenas as `<tr>` e `<td>`

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">email</th>
      <th scope="col">senha</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
  $email = $dados['email'];
  $senha = $dados['senha']; ?>
 <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><?php $email ?></td>
      <td><?php $senha ?></td>

    </tr> 
 <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Po, mano, era isso msm. Um mísero detalhe que me fez perder um tempo absurdo. Muitíssimo obrigado, mesmo. =)

Comment: De nada @PierryRodrigues se puder marca a resposta como correta.